# Forbidden: cannot access / on server

Tags: linux, perl, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently transferring a clients site over to our server, including the domain so it has the same URL etc. But upon transferring all the files over, and changing the `.htaccess` file to match the one on the old server, I am being greeted with the error message `You don't have permission to access / on this server` and I'm not really sure why? A few things to mention, changing the first line from `Options -Indexes` to `Options +Indexes` rectifies this, but instead of the error message I am greeted with `Index of /` page. Another possibility, but would switching the hosting platform from `Linux` to `Windows` fix these problems?

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 500 /error

<Files ~ "\.pm$">
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.template$">
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.tmpl$">
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.log$">
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.revid$">
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.pl
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^browse=show_contact$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://THE_DOMAIN_IS_HERE/formmail2.pl? [R=301,L]
```

One more thing I tried was adding `DirectoryIndex index.pl` which then brings up yet another error message, `cannot execute script...etc etc etc...index.pl`. I'm not really sure what to do, so any suggestions on how to rectify this will be massively appreciated!

Comment: First of all go into your log folder of your webserver /var/log/apache2/error* most times if not defined other else where  then when you got that log access your site so you get error and paste the last 20 lines here

Comment: oh and by the way YES Switching to windows will solve that problem because there are all users root and so there will be no permissions that will block :D

Comment: @FrankfromDSPEED thanks for your help btw, great so if I switch over to windows first, that should solve some of the problems

Comment: yes it 100% solves this permission issus.

Comment: @FrankfromDSPEED OK, cheers! I've switched over to Windows, I'll give it a few hours for the DNS changes to take effect and let you know what happens.

Comment: @FrankfromDSPEED you were correct, that did solve the permission issue. But now I'm just greeted with `http://DOMAIN_NAME_HERE.net /` and an index of all the files in `public_html` thus, it's not rendering the `index.pl` doc

Comment: Then look in your error log why probally you don't installed mod_pearl for your Apache and if you did then simply not installed or you i could gut imagin that your probally simply have no mime type for handling .pl files with mod_perl

Comment: Maybe download and use http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/xampp-win32-1.8.3-4-VC11-installer.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Answer is Easy since your on Linux

You simply have wrong permissions for your /var/www/index.pl
and thats why it can't be executed but / can be showed!
you need to do sudo chown rightuser:rightgroup the files in /var/www
and even make mod_perl be able to execute perl

to give you a more complet answer i would need to know the following
 - 1. Error log what i requested in Comment under your question
 - 2. The Operating System u are using
 - 3. The Webserver u are using and its exact version is it self compiled or from software repo of your Linux version.
 - 4. if from your linux version and is apache2 simply do 
    sudo ps aux | grep apache
else
    sudo ps aux | grep httpd
 - 5. Post all that here so i can help you